# Real time video streaming with ASP.net Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, streaming, h.264, ip-camera

My task is to pick up a video stream from an AXIS M1011 IP-camera and relay it to multiple clients with a REST web service.

The reason I'm using such a thing is because the camera can hold only up to 15-20 connections, and will have a bit more. Also there is some security and authentication issues, some additional features and so on. Basically the ideal thing is to have a "singlton" video streaming from the camera relayed to multiple clients.

The camera can stream MJPEG and H.264 stream and static images. I'm having troubles capturing the H.264 stream or MJPEG with the service. Since the H.264 stream is served via RTSP protocol, and the MJPEG has poor compression and I'm not clear how to resend it to the client.

So one of my ideas is to pull the current static image, for example, 25 times a second and somehow create an H.264 stream which would be streamed to the user. Is there any way to create one H.264 stream object which would be shown to all clients or not? Because what would a new client see if he connects later is the stream from the start of capturing. Does that mean I should start separate encoding processes for every connected client? That sounds like it is resource-hungry solution (reading and encoding images).

What would be the best path to take for this? Every advice would be a great help, code snippets even better.

Tnx in advance.

Comment: I do not understand how this question is related to Web API?

Comment: I'm using the Web API framework to build the service. That does not have a direct connection to the streaming problem, but it is a reference to the technology and language I am using.

Comment: Have you solved this problem?   I have a similar issue.   I'm looking at using signalR to broadcast out the images either from decoded MJPEG stream.

Comment: Hi Greg. At that time and age I didn't make it with any component from the .net stack. Websockets were not known to me then, so I did it another way. I did it with node.js + express at that point, and this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mjpeg-proxy, with some modifications. I extended my application with other features because it was hooked to an IP cam. To be honest, I see websockets fitting much better in this story than a plain REST API, with the drawback that you need a client understanding websockets, while with the previous HTTP is enough. You could probably do it the same way in .net.